# Why DB2 cannot allow creation of database with keyword "BACKUP" in its name?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I'm using DB2 Express C v 10.5

I'm trying to create databases with names "BACKUP", "BACKUPTEST", "BACKUP_TEST" and even "TEST_BACKUP".

In all above cases DB2 throws error as below:

SQL1001N "BACKUPTEST" is not a valid database name. SQLSTATE=2E000

---

I tried with following command, it didn't work.

```
> db2 create database BACKUP
```

or

```
> db2 create database "BACKUP"
```

This shows an error as:

> "SQL1001N  "BACKUP_TEST" is not a valid database name.  SQLSTATE=2E000"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no restriction on the specific name, other than it must be 8 characters or less.  So `BACKUP` works just fine as a database name:

```
$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: 
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10055" with level 
identifier "0606010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.0.5", "s141128", "IP23633", and Fix Pack 
"5".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5.5".

$ db2 "create database backup"
DB20000I  The CREATE DATABASE command completed successfully.
```